# What is Tree and Merge Source?

Tags: application-development, launchpad, bazaar, merge

I did a bzr merge, and I always forget what the merge source represents, and what the tree represents.

Which one is my code, and which one comes from the branch I merged with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TREE` is the current branch you are on. `MERGE-SOURCE` is the branch you merged from into the current branch.

Let's say you're on `trunk`, and you merge from some other branch `feature-123` and you get a conflict. If you look at the diff, you might see lines like these:

```
<<<<<<< TREE
changes you did
in your
current branch
=======
changes others did
in the
other branch
you're merging from
>>>>>>> MERGE-SOURCE
```

The lines between `TREE` and `======` are lines that were added in the current branch, `trunk`.
The lines between `=======` and `MERGE-SOURCE` are lines that were added in the other branch, `feature-123`.

Comment: It's even better that the official docs, +1. (http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.0.90/en/user-guide/conflicts.html)

Comment: @SylvainPineau I try. (I *did* write a book on this stuff, you know ;-) (see my profile ;-)

Comment: I've just read it (your profile). Good job!